# ng lint command is suceeds but VS code shows error

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, tslint

I am using tslint tool my angular project.

My tsconfig.json file

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",

        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2016",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "include": [ "src/main.ts" ]
}
```

The `ng lint` command shows no error however the VS code showing the
red error markers stating

> Experimental support for decorators is a
> feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the
> 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to
> remove this warning.ts(1219)

(I am using vs code for mac-os)

[image]

Note : I had tried with experimentalDecorators : false but the issue remains same also one of the project I downloaded from git have exactly same tsconfig.json and it works there in same vscode.

Can anyone point out why vscode showing errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think the typescript version in your package.json is older than the one that is being used by Visual Studio Code. In the bottom right of Visual Studio Code, click the TypeScript version and select the option of choose workspace version. Then the lint issue should go away.